# Socket.io doesn't work in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, vps

I have tried socket.io on localhost and it works perfectly. However, when in production I get the following error:

```
GET http://77.235.46.164:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1448754369321-21 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

On the server side I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
connection.connect();
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

While on the client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://77.235.46.164:3000'); .... etcs
```

I am also starting the node server (I have VPS account in EuroVPS).
I have searched everywhere but I don't seem to find a solution that works for me.

Comment: this question's title is misleading readers to think that the module is not ready. what are you setup in production? is it behind some proxy? or just nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it working without firewall?

In some controlled network Firewall may block websockets & ports other than 80,443.

Comment: I have been looking into this but I haven't found something concrete yet. I will let you know...

Comment: You can also check if 3000 port is open for outside world from VPS

Comment: Yes this was the solution, I had to open port 3000 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an HTTP server yourself,instead of having the Express framework create one for you, so you will be able to reuse your HTTP server, in order to keep the same server instance.

You can try :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Create your server
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

//Then you can listen for connection
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('an event sent to all connected clients')
  //Awesome things
})
```

Comment: this doesn't work either... I am trying to see if firewall is blocking the socket..